# How to detect if a given image is correct or not, with a given set of correct, fault sample images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have 2 image sets, one including 5 correct images and the other set including 10 fault images, fault images have 2 types

[correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faEFJ.png)

[fault image type 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz2bK.png)

[fault image type 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN3dO.png)

both types have slight differences with correct image.

Fault type 1 having a different shape of the box, and fault type 2 having more dark pixels in the image than the correct image.

I want to create a model which detects when an image is given, if it is a correct image or a fault image using Python and OpenCV.

Thought of using haar-cascading but i dont have confidence since the negative images are just slightly different with the positive images.

Which is the better approach to solve this? (traincascade or any other?)

Comment: Do you prefer to use deep learning techniques to solve this problem? I think I have a simpler solution... using OpenCV

Comment: @HowardGENG Since Im new to image processing stuff I thought of using machine learning as this has got a set of correct images and a set of fault images.
What about your solution???

Comment: So detecting faults amounts to detecting a non-rectangular outer boundary, and detecting too many dots on the object? That is fairly straight-forward, you don't need to learn any complex models for this. Do you have any real images? (I presume these simulated ones were meant for learning?) Real images tend to have lots of features that the idealized synthetic ones don't. Developing a method based off of synthetic images will give you a big surprise when you try to apply the method in the real world... :)

Comment: Hi Cherry, I have posted my answer. Hopefully, it could help you move forward. If you find my answer useful and it outputs what you expect, please accept as the answer to your question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Real correct images also doesnt have the well shpaed rectangles, their corners are bent, so any idea to detect the type 1 fault image with that condition? and how should the fault type 2 be detected (the one with too many dots)? When preprocessing the images I am not supposed to decide values for functions by my self, it should be reliable... :(

Comment: @HowardGENG Thanks a lot for your time Howard, I will try it out! :)

Comment: It is easy to ignore corners when determining the shape of an object. Or you could require that the opposite sides are parallel. The important thing is to develop the method using a set of real images as will be used when the method is placed in production. As long as you have examples of correct and defect, you can gather statistics on your measurements for these two groups, and determine robust thresholds. That is what you do with machine learning. Except that I like to feed machine learning with meaningful features rather than just pixels.

Comment: @CrisLuengo In brief, when I have multiple correct images and multiple defect images and im supposed to consider all those images when detecting, will there be a approach for me except machine learning?

Comment: That depends on what you call machine learning. I think here there is a simple image analysis algorithm that needs to be developed, which leads to a few features (related to how straight and parallel the edges are and how many dots there are). These features are fed into a simple machine learning tool such as a decision tree (i.e. you do statistics and determine thresholds for these features), which leads to a diagnostic ok/defect. -- To develop the image analysis algorithm you need a little bit of experience, but this one looks like an easy problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I meant using haar training (openCV traincascade) by generating sample images. I cant think of a method since there is a group of images to evaluate and decide whether correct or defect

Comment: You can try Haar cascades. But do train them with images actually obtained where the system will be used. You'll be surprised if you don't. And good luck detecting unexpected defects (i.e. defects not seen during training).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, then i will go for haar cascades with the images. Eventhough this is something extra,
I have seen in face detection examples where haar has been used, that negative samples are totally different from the positive images like in negative images there is no similar object at all. But in my case some negative images are almost same with the positives. Isn't that gonna be a problem?

Comment: @CrisLuengo When doing cascade training, are even 5 images going to be sufficient as positives if Im going to test with an image which is already used for positives ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how many images you will need to train for this task. You should not test with images used for training, they cannot tell you if the algorithm was able to generalize correctly from the training data, and will not tell you how well the algorithm will do in practice.

Comment: @CrisLuengo If it works fine with an image that was used for training, it means the process is ok isnt it? Then what I have to do is increasing the number of training images. I just want to make sure I do the cascade training right for the moment

Comment: Sure, the results on the training images should be really good.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is using OpenCV and Nump, in order to simplify the problem.

The approach would be:

1. compare the non-faulty image (benchmark image) with the input image.
2. Look at the size of detected contours.

First of all, we import the two major libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

Secondly, we define a function called find_faulty_type:

```
def find_faulty_type(benchmark_img, input_img):
    _, benchmark_img = cv2.threshold(benchmark_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    _, input_img = cv2.threshold(input_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    temp_img = benchmark_img - input_img
    if np.sum(temp_img) == 0:
        print ("No Fault")
    else:
        _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(temp_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        area_threshold = 6
        mean_area = 0
        for cnt in cnts:
            mean_area += cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        mean_area /= len(cnts)
        if mean_area >= area_threshold:
            print ("Type 1 Fault")
        else :
            print ("Type 2 Fault")

        output = cv2.cvtColor(temp_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        cv2.drawContours(output, cnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.imshow("type result", output)
        cv2.waitKey()
```

Example result image of Type 1 Fault:

[image]

Example result image of Type 2 Fault:

[image]

Thirdly, we load different images and test their faulty types, by doing something similar to the following:

```
ok_img = cv2.imread("ok_img.png", 0)
type1_img = cv2.imread("type1_img.png", 0)
type2_img = cv2.imread("type2_img.png", 0)

find_faulty_type(benchmark_img=ok_img, input_img=ok_img)
find_faulty_type(benchmark_img=ok_img, input_img=type1_img)
find_faulty_type(benchmark_img=ok_img, input_img=type2_img)
```

Enjoy and have fun, cheers.

Comment: Howard, Thank you for your code.What does the "area_threshold" mean? By the way in my problem there are 5 correct images and theres condition that the amount of correct images can be increased. How can that be applied to your solution?

Comment: This is very simplistic. In the real world, the object will not be in the same location within the image every time. If you want to do a direct comparison like this, there needs to be some registration (alignment) too.

Comment: Yes, object's location varies in every image and the size as well (slightly)

Comment: If your object is moving around. You then need to look at 2D ICP methods.

Comment: You should change  `_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(temp_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` to  `cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(temp_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` because it gives error not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2),in rest thanks for the solution!